# Assigning values to a struct based on column/value lists

Tags: elixir

I want to take lists containing columns and values in sequential order and turn it into a `struct`. I'm currently pattern matching on the values but as the lists continue to grow my code becomes bigger. Here's some code.

```
@find_account_query ~s{
  SELECT
    username, -- 1
    name, -- 2
    surname, -- 3
    account.active, -- 4
    CASE WHEN person_id IS NOT NULL
      THEN TRUE
    ELSE FALSE END AS isPerson -- 5
  FROM account
    LEFT JOIN person ON person.id = account.person_id
  WHERE username = $1
}


def get(username), do:
  conn 
  |> Connection.query(@find_account_query, [username])
  |> parse_acct

defp parse_acct({:ok, %{ :num_rows => 0 }}), do: nil
defp parse_acct({:ok, %{ :columns => columns, :rows => [account]}}), do: 
  account |> parse_acct

##### The following function clause will get really long
defp parse_acct([username, name, surname, active, is_person]), do:
  %Topaz.Account{
    username: username,
    name: name,
    surname: surname,
    active: active,
    is_person: is_person
  }

defp parse_acct(_), do: nil
```

How can I simplify the process of taking this from a `List` to a `struct`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the column list and value list align, you can iterate recursively through the column list and assign values to the struct based on index.

```
def get(username), do:
  conn
  |> Connection.query(@find_account_query, [username])
  |> getp

defp parse_acct({:ok, %{ :num_rows => 0 }}), do: nil
defp parse_acct({:ok, %{ :columns => columns,  :rows => [values]}}), do:
  parse_acct(columns, values, %Topaz.Account{}, 0)

defp parse_acct([head|tail], values, account, index) do
  # Get the corresponding atom in the model
  atom = head |> String.to_atom
  # Add the value to the account
  account = account |> Map.put(atom, values |> Enum.at(index))
  # Continue iterating
  parse_acct(tail, values, account, index + 1)
end

# When iteration is done, return account
defp parse_acct([], values, account, index), do: account
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the fact that a struct is just a map with a `:__struct__` key to build up a map, then add the appropriate `:__struct__` key. Something like this:

```
defp parse_acct(values), do:
  keys = [:username, :name, :surname, :active, :is_person]
  keys
    |> Enum.zip(values)
    |> Enum.into(%{})
    |> Map.merge(%Topaz.Account{})
end
```

You could go further and extract the keys list from the struct using something like this

```
%Topaz.Account{} |> Map.keys |> Enum.filter(&(&1 != :__struct__))
```

However that would require that your values were always passed in in the same order that Map enumerates keys (presumably alphabetically)